# Common ways of asking for someones phone number

Tags: syntax, set-phrases, counters

I saw somewhere today that [電話]{でんわ}[番号]{ばんごう}は何番ですか is used to ask for someone's phone number. It seemed strange to me since I usually hear it as [電話]{でんわ}[番号]{ばんごう}何ですか, and also because the literal translation "What are the **number**s, in your phone **number**?" sounds like it has some redundancy in it.

So my question is, which is more common?

Comment: So what are you really asking?  The questions in your final line?  Or are you trying to actually find more common ways to ask this?  Unclear to me.

Comment: @istrasci the one's in the last line. Sorry for the lack of clarity in my question

Comment: Is this question about redundancy, not about the popular expression when you ask a number, isn't it?

Comment: @Toshihiko it about both, but I'll edit it to be just about the popular expression

Comment: I'm writing an answer about the feature of Japanese... Is it waste?

Comment: No no no it's not a waste. I'll ask it as another question

Comment: @Toshihiko here's the new question [japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30856/is-repetition-of-words-in-questi](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30856/is-repetition-of-words-in-questions-such-as-the-%E7%95%AA-in-%E9%9B%BB%E8%A9%B1%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E7%95%AA%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B-common-in-japan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

あなたの電話番号は何番ですか? is a common way of asking someone’s telephone number. We don’t have distinction of singular and plural form as you know. So its direct translation would be “What (number) is your telephone number? We don’t think it’s redundant.

I think 貴方の電話, 何番ですか？is passable. But “貴方の電話番号は何ですか？” sounds weird and odd to me. You can also say “(あなたの)電話番号を教えて頂けますか？” in polite manner.

Comment: I have never said or heard another native Japanese speaker say 「あなたの電話番号は何番ですか?」 and you say that is "common".

Comment: Yes. I heard it million times.

Comment: @YoichiOishi to be honest, I can't say I ever heard "あなたの電話番号は何番ですか？" *verbatim* in a real world situation. Maybe in a classroom, as an example sentence, but frankly 99% of the time, it's 電話番号を教えていただけませんか (or variants). Even "電話番号いくつ？" and "電話番号頂戴" are fairly common.

Comment: @Amani Kilumanga. I've often heard あなたの電話番号(は)何番（ですか？ as I wrote. You may have heard "電話番号いくつ？” if you say so, but  I've never heard it. I think (あなたの） 電話番号を教えていただけませんか? is a standard expression for asking the phone number. If I ask someone "電話番号頂戴," he or she'll be shocked, and roll around, cause I'm taken as a 83 year-old puff.

Comment: @YoichiOishi I was surprised the first time I heard いくつ, but it pops up here and there among the (my?) younger generations. "頂戴" can definitely be inappropriate, but still common when... ahem... trying to get the private phone number of a potential love interest (to be as politically correct as possible) OR someone you know closely already.

Comment: 電話番号に「いくつ」はおかしいですよね…。「電話番号頂戴。」もちょっと…。（業者が電話で「電話番号頂戴できますか？」とかならいいそうな気がしますが。）「電話番号教えて。」のほうがよく聞きますよね。。。「あなたの電話番号は何番ですか？」は…「あんた、電話番号、何番？」とかなら京都あたりでは言いますが、「あなたの・・・」はあんまり言わないかな。。。(って、そこが問題じゃないのかな？)

Comment: ＠Felectur. Thank you for your concerns on my auditory sense. But, don’t worry, it’s working perfectly. I wrote (あなたの）電話番号を教えていただけませんか? is a standard form of asking question with あなたの in parenthesis. You may or may not use あなたの. You add あなたの、彼の、会社の when you need to specify. I’ve never or seldom at best heard a restaurant / hotel receptionist and shop clerk asks you in blunt way as電話番号を教えていただけませんか without adding あなた様の、お客様の. あなたの電話番号を教えていただけませんか? is nothing special as you make a fuss, unless you’re living in a small village you don’t need to discern people.

Answer (score 5):

I think both of your sentences are occasionally used but the most common way of saying it is "電話番号を教えてください".

Answer (score 3):

The 番 in 番号 is a part of the noun. The 番 in [何番]{なん・ばん} is a counter suffix ([助数詞]{じょ・すう・し}). Although these two 番s are same in kanji and pronunciation, their roles and nuances in a sentence are different.

It's common for native Japanese speakers to use counter suffixes, even if it sounds repetitive in a sentence.

For example, when someone goes to a bank which has a ticket dispenser for waiting line management, he may hear an announcement like this:

> 「お[待]{ま}たせいたしました。[受付]{うけ・つけ}番号[１５１]{ひゃく・ごじゅう・いち}[番]{ばん}の番号[札]{ふだ}をお[持]{も}ちのお[客様]{きゃく・さま}、[３]{さん}番[窓口]{まど・ぐち}までお[越]{こ}しください。」

This sentence contains four 番s, but it sounds natural and decent for most native Japanese speakers. Using counter suffixes in this way is a custom in Japanese language. A word with a counter suffix helps imagine the meaning very well and prevents ambiguity.

Counter suffixes clarify the meaning of a sentence. If another counter suffix is used, the meaning of a sentence changes totally. For example,

> 電話番号は何番ですか？ ＝ What is your phone number?
>
> 電話番号は[何件]{なん・けん}ですか？ ＝ How many phone numbers (are there)?
>
> 電話番号は[何個]{なん・こ}ですか？ ＝ How many phone numbers (are there)?
>
> 電話番号は[何桁]{なん・けた}ですか？ ＝ How many digits does the phone number have?

So, using a proper counter suffix is very important in Japanese language.

If you would google [“電話番号は何”](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E9%9B%BB%E8%A9%B1%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%22&oq=%22%E9%9B%BB%E8%A9%B1%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.4237j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) or [“電話番号何”](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E9%9B%BB%E8%A9%B1%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7%E4%BD%95%22&oq=%22%E9%9B%BB%E8%A9%B1%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7%E4%BD%95%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.360j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8), you would see that many people usually add the counter suffix 番 to the expression when they ask a phone number.

何 without 番 is usually used in a situation where someone asks the purpose or the meaning of a phone number, or where someone asks multiple things in a sentence.

Example 1:

> Person A「[０１２０]{ぜろ・いち・にー・ぜろ}で始まる電話番号は**何**ですか？」
>
> Person B「フリーダイヤルです。」

Example 2:

> Person A「[３桁]{さん・けた}電話番号で、[１７１]{いち・なな・いち}って**何**ですか？」
>
> Person B「[災害用伝言ダイヤル](https://www.ntt-east.co.jp/saigai/voice171/)です。」

Example 3:

> Person A「住所と電話番号は**何**ですか？」
>
> Person B「名簿で確認します。」

There are various expressions to ask a phone number in Japanese, actually. I selected some common expressions (including those which other users suggest in their answers and comments, in case you wonder) and placed them in politeness-degree order: 〔１〕 is not polite (doesn't mean rude. It can be nice and friendly if said nicely in an appropriate situation.), 〔９〕 is very polite or well-professionally polite, and 〔２〕〜〔８〕 are inbetween.

> 〔１〕「電話番号[何]{なに}？」(very casual)
>
> 〔２〕「電話番号[何番]{なん・ばん}？」／「電話番号教えて。」(casual)
>
> 〔３〕「電話番号、[聞]{き}いてもいい？」(nicer casual)
>
> 〔４〕「電話番号は[何]{なん}ですか？」(translation-from-other-language or simple keigo)
>
> 〔５〕「電話番号を教えてください。」(guide-like or direction-like keigo)
>
> 〔６〕「電話番号は何番ですか？」(friendly keigo)
>
> 〔７〕「電話番号、聞いてもいいですか？」(friendly keigo)
>
> 〔８〕「電話番号を教えていただけますか？」(formal keigo)
>
> 〔９〕「お電話番号をお伺いできますでしょうか？」(very formal keigo)

So, which the most common expression is depends on what politeness-degree someone is familiar with in one's daily life. Anyway, in many cases, using a proper counter suffix is nicer and more decent than not-using it.